# Below C code is valid or not?

Tags: c

While reading a post, I came across the following code and output of this code according to post is an error saying:

> Array element cannot be address of auto variable. It can be address of static or  external variables.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
 int a=5,b=10,c=15;
 int *arr[]={&a,&b,&c};
 printf("%d",*arr[1]);
 return 0;
 }
```

But when run this code on MinGW and online compiler it works fine without any error.

So would like to know this is perfectly valid or not??

Comment: Link us to the post you were referring to. Maybe you misunderstood it, but we can't tell what it says unless we see it.

Comment: http://cquestionbank.blogspot.com/2010/06/c-questions-on-pointers.html and its question number 6.

Comment: Questions 4 and 5 of your quiz are bullsh*t too, and question 8 is undefined behavior. Question 9 is complete nonsense, question 10 is not standard C, questions 11 and 12 have no point beside MSDOS, question 13 shows that its author is a moron which doesn't know about `<stdarg.h>`, 15 is UB, etc, etc. So if I were you I wouldn't give any credit to this link.

Comment: @Alexandre i agree with you on most of the questions but what the problem with question 9??

Comment: I mean the picture is nonsense. The strings have to reasons to be consecutive in memory. Also, should be `const char*` and not `char*`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking too. Half of that quiz is complete BS and it's making my eyes bleed.

Comment: But to be honest none here talking about the real point ,i mean what have been asked here!!

Comment: The real Thing Is what he said must be right Im just thinking to justify his answer even my compiler prompted me illegal initialization !

Comment: I just added a huge section to my answer about this.

Comment: After reading through this quiz, I think a PSA should be made to esnure that "Ritesh Kumar" the author of this terrible quiz never hold another C programming job again, unless he redoes all his CS coursework.

Answer (score 5):

In C99 that's OK, but ANSI is not.

Comment: This is the correct answer(although even before compilers started implementing C99, it was a common extension to allow constructs such as this)

Comment: @Alexandre Before C99, only constant-expression is permitted in square-brackets of array declaration.

Comment: I know that. But was it allowed in ISO C90 (not 89, sorry for the mistake) to initialize an array with pointers to automatic storage duration variables ?

Comment: @Alexandre Well, i am unsure of that, but i just know that C90 is more closer to ANSI (I couldn't obtain ISO 9899:1990). Depend on gcc .. -ansi, -std=iso9899:1990, -std=iso9899:199409 with -pedantic option reports same warning, but -std=c99 isn't.

Comment: @Aelxandre ah.. sorry for confusing designator and initializer.. according to http://www.coding-guidelines.com/cbook/cbook1_1.pdf (paragraph no. 1644), C90 still supports static storage duration for expressions in initializer ..

Comment: There's no practical difference between ANSI C89 and ISO C90, C90 is more or less just the ISO name for C89.

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me. I don't see anything wrong with it. If I had to nitpick, it'd be your formatting and indenting... But that's just about it.

EDIT:
I think what the post you were referring to meant is that you can't return the address of a local or auto variable. In this example, everything is in the same scope so it's perfectly fine.

EDIT 2:
Okay, going back to prior experience, I think I can find "some" weakness in the code. I've seen this on the Intel Compiler.

Since the variable is local, the compiler may promote it to a register. In that case addresses to it are invalid. However, modern compilers need to be able to trace this dependency and avoid putting that variable into a register.

In one case that I encountered a while back, I was accessing the address of the variable via inline assembly - something that the Intel Compiler could not trace. The compiler then promoted the variable to register and my inline assembly kept reading the old value on the stack rather than the register value.

Obviously it was something I shouldn't have done, but it would have been okay if the variable wasn't auto.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error message is a kinda bug of the compiler; it's an unnecessary restriction. Referencing auto (was: local) variables in an array is really dangerous, but in this case, the scope of the array and the referenced variables are the same (tought, it can be "exported" to other scopes, say, calling a function with the array, which grabs some elements of it). There are several ways to make such an error, even ones, which can't detected compile-time. Yes, pointers are dangerous, but life is so.

Comment: could you please highlight your point how Referencing auto variables in an array is dangerous??

Comment: Auto and local variables will fall out of scope. If the pointer to them is still alive and accessed later, the result is undefined.

Comment: This is no more dangerous than other common things one does in C.

Comment: The scope of a non-static variable expires outside of the block it's definied. Also, you may define pointers in a wider scope (say, global/static), which will contain invalid reference outside the original variable's scope. The really problem is that you will get no error at the holy moment. When you access a dead variable with a reference, it's about 50-90%, that you'll find it untouched, so you couldn't recognize the mistake for a while. Just as @nos said, it's no more dangerous than other things in C/C++. Design your program before write! etc.